# Kylo data_ingest feed job fails due to Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: mysql, apache-nifi, kylo

- I have setup a default template from Kylo installation directory for 'data_ingest' on kylo UI - http://localhost:8400
- Using the template I created a Feed to fetch data from database (MySQL) specifying database / table / columns in Feed details.
- The database was selected from a dropdown, I have given all configurations 
  inside /opt/kylo/kylo-services/application.properties

  ```
  spring.datasource.username=root
  spring.datasource.password=cloudera
  ..
  hive.metastore.datasource.username=root
  hive.metastore.datasource.password=cloudera
  ```

Despite this the job is failing for me with following error -

```
GetTableData[id=a3eb6450-1f53-3e1e-a523-01db02f0b625] Unable to execute SQL select from table due to StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=27219d8a-9bef-40be-a413-63d4d8663ebe,claim=,offset=0,name=32633830193154,size=0]; routing to failure: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Could not connect: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO))
```

[image]

Is there any configuration that I am missing causing this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To resolve this, provide the credentials for connecting to the database via the controller service. The steps are below:

1. Navigate to NiFi ([http://localhost:8079/nifi/](http://localhost:8079/nifi)).
2. Click the gear icon on the **NiFi Flow** process group on the canvas. This will open up **Process Group Configuration** page.

[image]

3. Navigate to **Controller Services** tab.
4. Locate the service of type **DBCPConnectionPool**. Depending upon the version of Kylo, this may be named **MySQL** or **Kylo MySQL**

[image]

5. Disable the service by clicking the lightning icon and clicking **Disable** button. Click **Close** after service is disabled.

[image]

6. Open the service configuration by clicking the pencil icon. This will open up **Configure Controller Service** popup.

[image]

7. Provide the correct database user name and password values for the properties **Database User** and **Password**

[image]

8. Click **Apply**. The configuration popup will close.
9. Enable the service by clicking the lightning icon, selecting **Service and referencing components** from the **Scope** dropdown and clicking **Enable**. Click **Close** after service is enabled.

[image]

10. Run the feed again.